# Multiple ssh remotes in one jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Could I use many remotes in one jenkins pipeline using SSH Pipeline Steps plugin?

Now my pipeline looks like this:

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = 'PRE-DEV'
remote.host = 'x.x.x.x'
remote.user = 'jenkins'
remote.identityFile = '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
remote.agentForwarding = true


pipeline {
agent any

stages{
   stage('BUILD'){
        steps{
            sshCommand remote: remote, command: "build commands"
        }
    }

    stage('UNIT TESTS'){
        steps{
           sshCommand remote: remote, command: "tests commands"
        }
    }

    stage('DEPLOY TO DEV'){
        steps{
            sshCommand remote: remote, command: "scp artifacts push to other vm"
        }
    }
}
```

Now i need additional stage ('RUN ON DEV'), where i can run my artifacts on other VM. How can i do it in the same pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## solution one:

you can just define another dict like blow:

```
def secondRemote = [:]
secondRemote.name = 'PRE-DEV'
secondRemote.host = 'your new host'
secondRemote.user = 'jenkins'
secondRemote.identityFile = '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa'
secondRemote.allowAnyHosts = true
secondRemote.agentForwarding = true
```

then use it by 
`sshCommand remote: secondRemote, command: "your new command"`

## solution two:

store your private key in jenkins credentials, then using ssh-agent plugin.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/